# Code::Blocks and Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, codeblocks

I´ve been trying desperately to get Qt4 running on my Code::Blocks. I´ve found the following page, with instructions I followed (German):

http://www.heikogorski.de/Compiler---Code/QT-und-Code--Blocks/qt-und-code--blocks.html

I downloaded Qt 4.8.2 like in the tutorial, checked every path 3 times and still, once I try to run the following very basic code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int a, char ** b)
{
    QApplication app(a,b);
    return app.exec();
}
```

the window will just crash and I get the following error message in debugger:

> Exception error at 0x6E1CC9A4 (QtCore4.dll) in qttest3.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Acesss violation at adress 0x01040806

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Are you perchance building your project using a compiler different than was used to build Qt?

Comment: I am using the GNU Compiler as on default

Comment: **Are you using the same compiler that was used to build the Qt you have installed**? If not, you will have problems. Either rebuild your own copy of Qt with the same compiler that Code::Blocks is using, or make sure that your Code::Blocks project is configured to use the compiler that Qt was compiled with.